# If $f$ is $C^1$ and $\Vert[Df(x)]^{-1}\Vert \leq c$ for all $x$, does the inverse $f^{-1}$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $V$ be a normed space, $U \subset V$ an open nonempty set and $f: U \rightarrow V$ be such that $f$ is $C^1$, $Df(x)$ is invertable and $\Vert[Df(x)]^{-1}\Vert \leq c$ for all $x \in U$. Does $f^{-1}$ exists?

I tried to use the inverse function theorem or use the derivative to show something like $\Vert x-y\Vert \leq c \Vert f(x) - f(y) \Vert$, but it only works locally. It seems to me that exists a $f$ with this properties with no inverse but trying to find it has been equally difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $\Bbb{C}$ as a two-dimensional real vector space, let $U = \{z : \Re(z)>0\}$, and consider $f : U \to \Bbb{C}, z \mapsto e^z$.

It is not hard to see that your condition is satisfied, but $f$ is not injective.